# How to classify expense receipt into categories with Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I think about integrating Azure Form Recognizer to our website to automatically handle the processing of uploaded invoice/expense receipts.
So far I have been trying the pretrained models for receipts and invoices, which works fine. They consist of all the relevant information, except that I need the receipt model to categorize the expense receipts into our intern custom categories.
When creating an expense, the user currently needs to select between one of 75 categories, a.e. if the expense is a travel expense or salary.
I want the model to do that automatically.
So the procedure should be as follows:
The user uploads an expense receipt document to our azure blob storage
and the model sends a response with all the data like tax rate, net price etc. including the category.
My though was that I might have to train a custom model for that. Since the category is not printed on the document im not sure how to do the labeling.
Is there a way to label the data into the categories?
Also is there a way to copy a pretrained model, so I won't have to label all the documents only to add the category?